# Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL Line/id was not found on this server

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ce3t.png)

Unable to Display my method **id** from the controller .

i tried to access my method id and i get an error .
Am i going somewhere wrong ?

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH')  or die('No Direct Script Access');

Class Controller_Line extends Controller
{
    public function action_index()
    {
       echo "<h1> Demonstration : KOHANA </h1>";
       echo "This is a Line 1.<br>";
       echo "This is a Line 2.<br>";
       echo "This is a Line 3.<br>";
       echo "This is a Line 4.<br>";
    }

    public function id()
    {
      echo "this is method id";
    }
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: We need to see the context in which you are invoking id(). And the error message would also be helpful.

Comment: @Gordon i have added an image & the title is the error by the way

Comment: my naive guess would be the method needs to be named action_id() for the router to be able to call it.

Comment: Thanks a Bunch !!!!!!!!!! @Gordon it works !!! yayyyyy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller actions needs to be prefixed with `action_` for the router to be able to call it. So the method needs to be named `action_id()`.